# Flutter SearchDelegate: How to change the color of the blue bubbles from text cursor and select?

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter SearchDelegate: How to change the color of the blue bubbles in search delegate widget in flutter?

environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

[image]

[image]

In my Scaffold-Appbar i have an action with an IconButton and then i call DataSearch. Then i set the ThemeData appBarTheme in the DataSearch. Thats it.

```
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {
              showSearch(context: context, delegate: DataSearch());
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),


class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    return ThemeData(
      textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
        //cursorColor: Colors.red,
        selectionHandleColor: Colors.red,
        //selectionColor: Colors.white,
      ), // cursor color
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the color within the `textSelectionTheme` by setting the [selectionHandleColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextSelectionThemeData/selectionHandleColor.html).

```
textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
        selectionHandleColor: Colors.red, // Change bubble to red
        cursorColor: Colors.white,
      ),
```

EDIT: Full Example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
          selectionHandleColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        primaryColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: TextField(),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('MyApp'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result: 
[image]

Comment: selectionHandleColor not working. cursorColor works fine.

Comment: Not sure why it is not working for you. My bubble color changed to red with this example and worked completely fine :/

Comment: i created a new empty project and only with your solution and it's also not working, so i put some more code and description in the question

Comment: maybe you can share a small example project to github and post it here. thanks.

Comment: It's not working in the SearchDelegate-ThemeData, but it works in the MaterialApp-ThemeData, means it takes over to all SearchDelegates. i.e. selectionColor has to be set up in each SearchDelegate-ThemeData.

Comment: Hi quoci. Can you test that in DarkMode, is it working in your project with "themeMode: ThemeMode.system, darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),"? Or do you already have a tip/solution for me? Thank you. --- In LightMode its ok, but in DarkMode its blue again. Without the two lines themeMode and darkTheme its working.